# 2010: Hide list column in display form if it is empty

Tags: 2010, column, display-form

How can a list column be hidden in the display form if it is blank?

Answer (score 1):

There is no SharePoint-Way (i.e. out-of-the-box) to do this. You *might* be able to add a [`content editor webpart`](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/05/09/adding-script-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp-in-sharepoint-2010-aspx/) to the page and in there, using javascript, do some magic...

But I would advice against it: Column sorting and filtering (and other stuff) might rely on the number of columns (and all of them being visible...). You would need to do some real thorough testing if you do this.

And imagine you have a list with many items: The view will be paged. Will the column be hidden on page one, visible on page two and again hidden on page three? I'd guess such a behaviour will puzzle every user in believing SharePoint to be "unreliable".

Comment: This is my code. It didn't work

` var test = $("input[title='test']").val();
        if(test == '') {
            $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('test')").closest("tr").hide();   
}`

Comment: Sorry, I have no SP2010 to test this with. Does this work, when you run it in the console? Is jQuery loaded? Isn't `$("input[title='test']").val()` an array? if so, `test == ''` would be false...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery to achieve this as the following

- Edit your display form page.
- Add Script Editor.
- Add the following code to script editor .

**Code**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('h3:contains("yourcolumnname")').closest('td').next('td').text() == '')
{
$('h3:contains("yourcolumnname")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('h3:contains("yourcolumnname")').closest('tr').show();
}
});

    </script>
```

You may need to check also [Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)